# Calling form action from an input

Tags: html, forms, input, submit, action

I am trying to create a form that'll send POST data to the entered website.

```
<form method="post" action="(Here's where I need to get the website URL into from the input below)">
<div id="website">
<input name="site" id="site" value="" placeholder="http://example.com">
</div>
<input name="data" value="">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

How would I go about doing this? What I want is for you to type in a website and the post data, and it'll send the data to the entered website.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/bhilleli/Vyu64/5/

Basically, I just created an event in the textbox, so every time something is entered in the textbox, the action for the form gets updated.

```
<form method="post" id="myForm" action="">
<div id="website">
<input name="site" id="site" value="" placeholder="http://example.com">
</div>
<input name="data" value="">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

JS

```
window.onload = function(e) {  
    document.getElementById("site").onkeyup=function(e) {
        document.getElementById("myForm").action=document.getElementById("site").value;  
        console.log(document.getElementById("myForm").action);
    }
}
```